# App crashes while Modal view controller closes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to display the `modalViewControlle`r from the 2nd screen of the app, and when I dismiss the controller it should navigate to the 1st screen. The below code works fine in iPhone 4, 5 and iPod Touch but NOT in iPAD. The objective is when I dismiss the `modalViewController` it shouldn't go back to the second screen, but it should display the first screen.

```
        ShareEmail *shareEmail = [[ShareEmail alloc] initWithNibName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",xibShareEmail] bundle:nil];

        shareEmail.fromWer = @"ownPer";
        [self presentModalViewController:shareEmail animated:NO];
        [shareEmail release];

        [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

In share email class

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Aren't you releasing `shareEmail` while it's still being displayed?

Comment: First of all, you're using methods that are deprecated. You should be using presentViewController:animated:completion and dismissViewControllerAnimate:completion.

Second, you're dismissing the modally displayed controller from the wrong class. It's the responsibility of the class that displayed a modal controller to dismiss it; so that code should go in the class in which you allocated and presented your ShareEmail view controller, not within the ShareEmail view controller itself. Might not fix the crash, but start off by following these steps to eliminate the most obvious source of problems.

Comment: The release should be fine, as a general rule you're not responsible for retaining objects that you pass into such methods. However, the UIViewController documentation isn't exactly clear on this point, so using autorelease would be the safest. Using ARC would be the best solution to the release quandary though!

Comment: Thanks @petemorris. I cant figure out exactly. This works fine in iPhone. But I have this problem occurs in iPad. or is there any alternative method?

Comment: Is there any output to the console when this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something interesting is happening. You are presenting a view controller from `self`, and then you're having the `navigationController` perform its backwards navigation. At this point, the `self` I was talking about earlier disappears.

Remove the `popViewController` method from your `presentViewController` method.

Also, you'll need to use the `^completion` handler method. That's where you should put your navigation controller `pop` code.

```
-(void)present {
    ShareEmail *email = [[ShareEmail...
    //You'll need to get a weak reference to `self` in `email`
    email.modalDelegate = self; //you need to make a property in ShareEmail
    [self presentViewController:email animated:YES completion:nil];
    [email release];
}

-(void)dismiss {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
}

//in ShareEmail.m
[modalDelegate dismiss];
```

Comment: If you have `-release` in your code you're not using arc. You should migrate to arc, makes a lot of this stuff easier

Comment: If I migrate to arc then it wont support iOS 5 or lower. How can I adapt all ios versions with the arc. any idea?

Comment: iOS4 supports ARC, but not all the conventions like <weak>. I don't think many apps support iOS4 anymore anyway. All "current" devices support iOS6 now, and soon iOS7. The lone holdout is the iPad 1, I believe

Answer (score 1):

You need to retain your shareEmail view controller - make a synthesized retained property

YourClass.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ShareEmail *shareEmailViewController;
```

YourClass.m:

```
@synthesize shareEmailViewController;
```

Then display your modal view controller by:

```
ShareEmail *shareEmail = [[ShareEmail alloc] initWithNibName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",xibShareEmail] bundle:nil];
self.shareEmailViewController = shareEmail;
[self presentModalViewController:shareEmail animated:NO];
[shareEmail release];
```

The retained property will keep the view controller from being deallocated while in use.  Then when you dismiss it later you can do:

```
[self.shareEmailViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
self.shareEmailViewController = nil;
```

which will release the retained property and free the memory after you're done with it.